# Android and Gson Conversion to List<>

Tags: android, gson

I'm creating my first Android application, and utilizing the Gson library to convert some custom objects to strings and back. I can convert an individual custom object back and forth easily, but run into trouble when attempting to convert a List of custom objects.

I know this probably isn't the most practical usage, but it's a short term solution. Here is the code:

```
List<CarObj>cars = dealership.getCar(); // grabbing the cars list from another object
String carsListString = gson.toJson(cars); // convert to json string
```

This won't compile....says it's expecting an expression. I've got the class definition parameter, and the json string, but I don't know what's missing:

```
List<CarObj>theCars = gson.fromJson(List<CarObj>, carListString);
```

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
List<CarObj> cars = gson.fromJson(carsListString, new TypeToken<List<CarObj>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: hello this works perfectly , can you tell me  if i want to add a single item to a list of a <someclass>type how is this possible with cars.add(message); , i am trying this to add items to the end of a list of type chat beans to show chat messages first i.e update recyclerview ui first and make an api call later .